# Android:How to change the draghandle in a listview?

Tags: android, android-listview

`android:fastScrollEnabled="true"`

which workes fine but the drag handle which appears is very ugly and i need to change it..

is their any direct method to change the image of the draghandle to something i want ??

If not what should be done?

Note:I am not asking for code,just guide me through it.Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just an image, so you can easily change it.

Add something like that to you application theme :

```
<item name="android:fastScrollThumbDrawable">@drawable/apptheme_fastscroll_thumb_holo</item>
```

Which refers to a drawable with 2 states :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/apptheme_fastscroll_thumb_pressed_holo" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/apptheme_fastscroll_thumb_default_holo" />
</selector>
```

You can see an examle of what the drawable should be here : [Android Holo Colors](http://android-holo-colors.com/) (enable Fast Scrool at the end of the list). It will look like that :

[image] [image]

Comment: thanx,i can only accept your answer after 3 mins...i have given +1 for a small answer